# Is it possible to dynamically set properties of an `Object` using Apex?

Tags: apex, object, dynamic-apex

**Background**

I would like to be able to dynamically set properties of an `Object` (**not** `SObject`).

Given this class:

```
public class Invoice {
    public String Ref { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
Invoice inv = new Invoice();
inv.put('Ref', 'REF123');
```

But when I do `Execute Anonymous Apex` with above code, I this error:

> ERROR:  Compilation failed.
>    !    ERROR: Line: 3, Column: 12
>    !    Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void put(String, String)
>    !    from the type Invoice
>   ERROR:  Execution failed.

**Question**

1. Is it possible to dynamically set properties of an `Object` (**not** `SObject`) using Apex?
2. How would I dynamically set a property of an `Object` using Apex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some isolated cases - yours is one of them - there is this (ab)use of the serialize methods:

```
Invoice inv = (Invoice) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(new Map<<String, Object>{
    'Ref' => 'REF123'
})), Invoice.class);
```

Here, the capability of `JSON.deserialize` to create an instance of the specified type and set the properties of the instance is being used.

But in general, Apex is missing the map-like behavior for objects or a [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) API.

Comment: I should add, on a tangent, that I frequently use this capability in unit tests to mock up objects that have normally read-only fields.

Comment: Hi @CharlesT, I had assumed that the properties had to be public, but your comment makes me wonder...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Keith's answer, you can use `deserializeUntyped` to change an `Object` that already exists.  Keep in mind that the code below is going to copy the object, so any other references will still reference the old value.

```
Invoice inv = new Invoice();
inv.Ref = '123';
Map<String, Object> invMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(inv));
invMap.put('Ref', '456');
inv = (Invoice)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(invMap), Invoice.class);
```