# How to pass paramters to a dynamically created apex class

Tags: apex

is there a way to pass in parameters to a class when creating it dynamically using Type.forName(classname).newInstance().

```
global with sharing class ManagerBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
         Boolean isIndependent = true;
         global ILM_AddressSharingManagerBatch(Boolean indep) {
               isIndependent = indep;
        }
    }
```

```
global with sharing class ILM_BatchController implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
     // implementation
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
       DMT_Batch_Setting__mdt batchSetting = (DMT_Batch_Setting__mdt)pq.dequeue();
       String batchClassName = batchSetting.Batch_Class_Name__c;
       Type batchType = Type.forName(batchClassName);
       Database.Batchable<sObject> batchToExecute =
                    (Database.Batchable<sObject>)batchType.newInstance();
       Database.executeBatch(batchToExecute);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create an abstract batch class and created a `setIndependence` method for it however i have a problem casting the type properly:
source:([Call Parametrized constructor using Type.newInstance()?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222879/call-parametrized-constructor-using-type-newinstance))

```
public abstract class AbstractBatch 
{
    Boolean isIndepedent;
    public AbstractBatch setindependence(Boolean indepedent)
    {
        isIndepedent = indepedent;
        return this;
    }

}


global with sharing class ILM_BatchController implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
     // implementation
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
       DMT_Batch_Setting__mdt batchSetting = (DMT_Batch_Setting__mdt)pq.dequeue();
       String batchClassName = batchSetting.Batch_Class_Name__c;
           (AbstractBatch) batchType = ((AbstractBatch)Type.forName(batchClassName)).setindependence(false);
       Database.Batchable<sObject> batchToExecute =
                    (Database.Batchable<sObject>)batchType.newInstance();
       Database.executeBatch(batchToExecute);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Error: incompatible type since `system.type` is never an instance of `abstractBatch`.

Comment: To format your code, please select the entire block and click `{}` or press Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 3):

There is this technique [Is it possible to dynamically set properties of an `Object` using Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260323/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-set-properties-of-an-object-using-apex/260324#260324):

```
Type t = Type.forName(batchClassName);
Database.Batchable<sObject> b = (Database.Batchable<sObject>) JSON.deserialize(
    JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{'isIndependent' => false})),
    t
);
```

but the class would need a no-args constructor and a public property:

```
public with sharing class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    public Boolean isIndependent = true;
    public MyBatchable() {
    }
    ...
}
```

The trick here is to deserialize into a specific type where the deserialization sets the properties of the object.

Comment: getting error argument 1 cannot be null

Comment: @HamzaAlvi Check if your `batchType` is null.

Comment: wait the error is occuring in the start method of the batch class, its saying  the argument to the start method i.e Database.batchableContext BC is null.

Comment: @HamzaAlvi What line of code is reported as having the problem?

Comment: batchable context is null in the batch class's start method. even though its not null the value is the this: VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [15]|BC|{"jobId":"7070i000000wodOAAQ"}|0x185f033f

Comment: @HamzaAlvi Don't think that has anything to do with the code I posted.

Comment: Wait so i found the problem. There are other instance variables in my batch class and they are not being initialized, where should i initialize them?

Comment: @HamzaAlvi If you want to pass them in, set them (by name) via the JSON mechanism.